# ssh: port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssh

First, good morning. After running a DigitalOcean internet tutorial that taught how to set up a web server with Django, I had problems connecting via SSH, however, the site continues to run and accept HTTPS connections without any obstacles on the web.

To check availability, I pinged [Public IPv4 Address] [Public IPv4 DNS] and got no response. Since my website has a purchased DNS, I tried to ping [my website's private DNS] and also no response.

I researched possible errors and I'm already advancing: My security group has the rules: HTTP 80, SSH 22 and HTTPS 443 with any source of IPv4 released. So much so that I did all the server configuration via SSH.

I had already done this process before and had the same error, but since it was a test server, I didn't pay much attention. But now, after performing a change from HTTP to HTTPS (to make the site secure) it happens again!
Here are the tutorials:

Installing the webserver: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

How to secure Nginx (HTTP to HTTPS): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Any help is welcome and I thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you setup everything with ssh in the node and now you can't? Or the server is different now? By the way, timeout means your request doesn't reach to the instance. If your instance has a public ip(and has accesst to internet) and SG allows port 22 , I would check how are you accessing it via ssh. Care to share the ssh command ? Also, what does `telnet $yourec2publicip 22` give?

Comment: Yes, I set everything up over SSH. The server is the same.
I have a hypothesis. In the second example, in the part
"Step 3 — Allowing HTTPS Through the Firewall" turns on a Firewall
is he barring the entry via SSH? How can I provide my SSH pass?

Comment: And as for the `telnet [ip of EC2] 22` command just pops up trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04), in the part "Step 3 — Allowing HTTPS through the firewall", to check the status of the Firewall the following command was used:

`$ sudo ufw status`

But the output was:

```
Output:
Status: inactive
```

To work around this problem, I ran:

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Output:
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

However, AWS itself provides a Firewall system in connection permissions of groups related to the instance.
That way, I ended up "turning off" SSH and only allowing HTTPS traffic, so my server kept running.

So, summary: I couldn't connect via SSH due to running a manual Firewall that overrode the EC2 Instance's Groups control

Thank you for trying to help me! Success!

Comment: Hi, then what solution did you do to access via SSH?

Comment: I recreated the machine and stopped using the "ufw" command so as not to need to recreate connection rules, as AWS already does this automatically.